# What would be the special character for this mathematical notation?

Tags: formatting, named-characters

What would be the special character for this mathematical notation?

[image]

And how do I enter the $H$ and $0$? What are the Special Characters?

I searched information about this bar in another site to get the specific name of this character: [Link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40160/math-symbol-question-vertical-bar-for-evaluated-at)

Comment: If all you are trying to do is format the expression then 

`(V == HoldForm[A/H^2] Subsuperscript[Abs[HoldForm[h^3/3]], 0, 
     H]) // TraditionalForm`

Comment: This is the list of all special characters: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ListingOfNamedCharacters.html

Comment: @Kuba For kindness Could you review if the title and content is more compatible with my need?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\[DoubleVerticalBar]` behaves like a binary operator (often used to indicate parallel lines in geometry). You probably want

```
Subsuperscript[\[LeftDoubleBracketingBar] h/3 \[RightDoubleBracketingBar], 0, H] // 
  TraditionalForm
```

which gives

[image: form]

Comment: @LCarvalho That would seem like an easy thing to test for yourself, wouldn't it?

Comment: @LCarvalho You could try one of the free online $\LaTeX$ interpreters, e.g. https://latexbase.com/

Comment: What I needed in Latex is [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/374801/i-have-not-found-the-appropriate-character-that-resembles-a-vertical-bar/374807#374807)

Answer (score 6):

[Bob Hanlon's comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148265/what-would-be-the-special-character-for-this-mathematical-notation#comment398127_148265) is closer to what I was expecting, but it may be that [m_goldberg's notation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148265/what-would-be-the-special-character-for-this-mathematical-notation/148267#148267) may be more correct. In doubt, I'll post this:

```
(V == HoldForm[A/H^2] Subsuperscript[Abs[HoldForm[h^3/3]], 0, H])
```

[image: Imagem1]